# ReactJS OnKeyUp event not getting value on controlled input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, controlled-component

I'm building a ReactJS search component for data filtering through search.

The idea is that the user types a word, letter after letter, and the system will filter all registers containing that word. The basic component is detailed below:

```
class SearchInput extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        onKeyUp: PropTypes.func,
        placeHolder: PropTypes.string,
        value: PropTypes.string
    };

state = {
    searchText: ""
};

handleKeyUp = event => {

    console.log(event.target.value) // <== No result. Always empty

    let newSearchText = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ searchText: newSearchText });
    if (this.props.onKeyUp) this.props.onKeyUp(newSearchText);
};

render() {
    console.log(this.state.searchText) // <== Always empty

    return (
        <div className="search-input">
            <div className="search-input-icon">
                <Icon name="faSearch" />
            </div>
            <input
                autoFocus="true" 
                type="text"
                onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
                placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
                value={this.state.searchText}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

I'm not getting the key pressed value on the `handleKeyUp` event handler.

It works if I ommit the `value={this.state.searchText}` (uncontrolled) from the code, but I need a way to set the `searchText` from outside the component (initialization, other component selection, etc.).

Why am I not getting the `event.target.value` data on my handler? How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have to listen to the `onChange` event on an input field to get the updated target value. simply change

```
<input onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp} />
```

to

```
<input onChange={this.handleKeyUp} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
let newSearchText = event.target.getAttribute('value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `event.key` instead.

The `event.target.value` just points to your `this.state.searchText` which hasn't been set yet.

Answer (score 0):

seems you forgot to bind the function on the constructor:

```
class SearchInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
  }

  //... any code here

  handleKeyUp = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    //... any code here

    <input
      autoFocus="true" 
      type="text"
      onKeyUp={this.handleKeyUp}
      placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
      value={this.state.searchText}
    />
  }
}
```

Comment: or use `onChange` instead of `onKeyUp` more reliable I think... unless you need to trigger keyboard enter or something like that